# I have created one button. I want to redirect to another page by clicking on it in backbone. How can i do that?

Tags: backbone.js

I have created one button. I want to redirect to another page by clicking on it in backbone. How can i do that?
I tried following code but it does not work:

```
router.navigate("/file:///code/order/table.html",true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript:

`window.location.href = 'file:///code/order/table.html';`

But I would suggest to use relative path and simple anchor tag:

`<a href="table.html">Table</a>`

Answer (score 0):

the backbone router usage is wrong here. from the [doc](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-navigate) `router.navigate(fragment, [options])` this is the function usage, the 1st argument should be fragment, which is registered via the `router.routes`.

if you would like to navigate to the other file, you may consider the `window.location.href`